# Permissions Issue on SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, permissions

I have just moved a database from our test server to the live server by creating an empty database and restoring a backup to it.

Despite adding the Login correctly, I am getting the following error:

> The server principal "myUser" is not able to access the database
>   "myDatabase" under the current security context.

I have tried clicking F7 in Object Explorer Details with no luck. I can get the error simply by running:

```
> USE myDatabase 
> GO
> 
> EXECUTE AS LOGIN = 'myUser'
```

Running the following script (from a related question) shows the user correctly

```
select  princ.type_desc
,       princ.name
,       perm.permission_name
,       perm.state_desc
,       object_name(perm.major_id)
from    sys.database_permissions perm
left join
        sys.database_principals princ
on      princ.principal_id  = perm.grantee_principal_id
```

> SQL_USER  myUser  CONNECT GRANT

Any suggestions???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [sp_change_users_login](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174378.aspx) with the "Auto_Fix" action to resync the logins between the server and the database.

```
exec sp_change_users_login @Action = 'Auto_Fix', @UserNamePattern = 'myUser'
```

Comment: Thanks - I can low log into the database. However I still have an encryption key permission issue which I'll ask in another question. Thanks again!